# expo push notifications working at expo app but not working for android on production

Tags: push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo-notifications

for my expo project i have configured push notifications using Expo-notifications
it's working fine for ios apps published on app store
But, for android it only work using expo app

android and notification part in app.json :

```
"android": {
  "package": "com.fluffy.bunny",
  "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
  "versionCode": 106,
  "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
  "permissions": ["RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED","SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"],
  "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  },
  "splash": {
    "image": "./assets/splash.png",
    "resizeMode": "contain",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  }

},
"notification":
 { 
  "icon": "./assets/notiIcon.png",
  "color": "#ffffff", 
  "iosDisplayInForeground": true 
},
```

i added the package name to my android key and i added fcm server key to expo credentials.
i included the google-services file with the right server key inside it.
i added android.useNextNotificationsApi and "permissions": ["RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED","SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"] to my app.json file
and still none of that is working for android app.